# How do I check a remote git repository is at a particular version?

Tags: git

Before I build a release of an application, I want to make sure a git repository used to build one of its dependencies has not changed.

Is there a way to query a remote bare repository branch for it's version?

In subversion, I can use

```
svn info <url>
```

and I get back the revision. I want to effectively do the same thing.

Is there a way to get the hash, so I can compare it? I don't really want to get the whole repository to do this if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Git you do this by first fetching the remote state: `git fetch origin`. This talks to the remote repository and stores all information in your local repository.

Assuming your branch is `master`, you then compare the difference between the head commit of `master` (the local branch) and  the head commit of `origin/master` (the remote branch):

```
git diff master..origin/master
```

This will show you the differences between local and remote (add `--name-status` to have a SVN-like summary).

You can also just type `git status`, and Git will tell you if your branch is in sync with `origin`, or ahead of it.

Answer (score 1):

Git is distributed-version-control-system (DVCS), so you have to get whole repository on your machine to work with it.

To sync with remote branch do `git fetch origin`.

After that, if you type:

```
git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate
```

you should look for `origin/master` or `origin/HEAD`. For fuller commit descriptions omit `--oneline` argument.